# How do I determine which MS Edge Driver is compatible with my OS Version to enable web automation with Selenium for Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, webdrivermanager-python

I've been using Selenium with the Edge Driver for some time. I've been instantiating my Edge Driver by specifying the `executable_path=` parameter with no issues. However, I recently switched my web automation project to use the `webdriver_manager`, i.e., `webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager`. Now, when I command the driver to navigate to any webpage - it opens for one second, then immediately closes. The current troubleshooting step I'm on is ensuring that the Edge Driver I'm using (the one downloaded by using the `webdriver_manager` module) is compatible with my current OS Version, but now I'm stumped. I don't know how to find which MS Edge Driver is compatible/correct for my current OS build - I see no patterns when comparing the two, e.g.:

My current OS:

[image]

The webdriver downloaded by the `webdriver_manager`:

[image]

And here is a link to all MS Edge Drivers:

https://msedgewebdriverstorage.z22.web.core.windows.net/

So, how do I find the Edge Driver that is "right" for my OS? When I look at these two numbers: OS build - 22000.795 and Edge webdriver version - 103.0.1264.77; I see no pattern or way of determining which driver is compatible. Maybe, I'm using the `webdriver_manager` module improperly? I know I can use the executable path, but I'm under the impression that using the `webriver_manager` automates the install of new releases for you so you don't have to update your script to new edge drivers in the future.

For additional context, here is my code (using Facebook's domain just as an example):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service as EdgeService
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Edge(service = EdgeService(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install()))

driver.get('https://facebook.com')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now (i.e., with the same code example in my original question, the MS Edge window now opens as commanded and remains open). I found the MS Docs regarding Edge webdriver installation/configuration

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=c-sharp

and here are the steps I followed:

1. The first step is to ensure that your Edge webdriver ("msedgedriver.exe") version matches your Edge *browser* version (I read a tech blog that said my OS build version needed to match my "msedgedriver.exe" version - thinking maybe that's wrong now?)
2. I navigated to **About Microsoft Edge** in settings: edge://settings/help

which displays my current MS Edge version - It was covered with a prompt to update Edge - so I did. Checked after update and my version was: `104.0.1293.47`

3. On a whim, suspecting that maybe my Edge browser update was the cause for `webdriver_manager` downloading the incompatible `msedgedriver.exe`, I attempted to run my script again (exact same one I posted in original question)

And it worked - I checked the `msedgedriver.exe` version right after and noticed that `webdriver_manager` downloaded a new version: 104.0.1293 - which matches my current Edge Browser version.

So, I'm not 100% sure what the cause for the `webdriver_manager` failing to download the correct version (to match my browser) was - but until I updated my MS Edge Browser, no new drivers were installed. Then after update and running the script, the right driver is installed and it's working fine now.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community member in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

The [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) driver manager works well with Edge:

```py
from seleniumbase import get_driver

driver = get_driver("edge", headless=False)
driver.get("https://facebook.com")
import time; time.sleep(1)
driver.quit()
```

(Here's another example using the raw driver manager: [raw_browser_launcher.py](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/raw_browser_launcher.py))

Alternatively, you can use the more simple format with automatic setUp and tearDown, but then you need to run your test with `pytest` and add `--edge` as a command-line option to use Edge:

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase

class MyTestClass(BaseCase):
    def test_facebook(self):
        self.open("https://facebook.com")
        self.sleep(1)
```

```bash
pytest test_facebook.py --edge
========================= test session starts ==========================
platform darwin -- Python 3.10.5, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /Users/michael/github/SeleniumBase/examples, configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: html-2.0.1, xdist-2.5.0, forked-1.4.0, rerunfailures-10.2, ordering-0.6, cov-3.0.0, metadata-2.0.2, seleniumbase-3.5.11
collected 1 item                                                       

test_facebook.py .

========================== 1 passed in 4.40s ===========================
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer Michael! I attempted to use ```seleniumbase``` just like your example. Instantiated the driver okay, but same issue with Edge Browser window closing after one second. I actually figured it out thankfully (not 100% sure, but I think I needed to update my Edge Browser itself) - will be posting what I found as an answer.

Comment: In my examples, I have the test sleep for one second so that you can see the browser before it closes. That's expected in the exact examples I posted above.

Comment: Gotcha, sorry should have clarified, I excluded the ```driver.quit()``` line. Thanks for taking the time to explain - I haven't been introduced to seleniumbase (the selenium modules themselves are a lot to get used to - lol). Do you recommend using seleniumbase for specific web automation tasks?

Comment: I recommend SeleniumBase, as it simplifies the test creation process with Selenium Python, as well as handling driver-management. The pytest command-line options let you customize tests without rewriting them. And there's a Recorder to help you record and generate new tests quickly.